# How do I pass a variable through a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hyperlink, asp-classic

I would like to start off saying that I'm very new to programming. I am developing a site (www.example.com) that has multiple hyperlinks.

When a user visits my site I want all the links to be defaulted to the back office of another site (www.tvcmatrix.com/mhammonds) I use. How do I set the links to redirect to the query string value based on inputted text from a form that is on my site (www.example.com)?

In other words, if the url reads www.example.com/?user=abelliard, how do I make all the links on the site change to "www.tvcmatrix.com/abelliard"? If no query string is present, then I would like for the links to be www.tvcmatrix.com/mhammonds.

Here is a file on my site for the form called "form.asp"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="viral.asp" method="get" name="input" target="_self">
            Your TVC Matrix Associate ID: <input type="text" name="user" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the "viral.asp" file in the "form.asp" file.

```js
<%@ language="javascript"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <%
        var id = Request.QueryString("user");                    
        Response.Write("Your URL is: www.mca.com/?user=" + id)
    %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the last file and front end of the site called "front.asp"

I have 'viral' and 'form' down packed. The main thing I needed help with was the front end of the site that deals with the links.

I have no clue if I am even a tad bit close or way off track, but what I have isn't working at all so I know it's wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Site</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <a href="http://www.tvcmatrix.com/" + id="function" target="_blank" name="link">Click Here!</a>
            <iframe width="450" height="40" src="form.asp">                
            </iframe>
        </body> 
            <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                function tvcid() {
                    var username = document.getElementById('username');
                    if (username.value != "") {
                        tvcid = "username";
                    }
                    else {
                        tvcid = "mhammonds";
                    }
                }
            </script>               
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I pass a variable through a hyperlink?

For staters, you're not using a hyperlink, you're submitting a form.

`Request.QueryString("user");` is looking for something on the querystring. You're using POST, which has form fields.

Use `Request("user");`, which will grab the value regardless of whether it's on the querystring or a POST field. If you want to force recognition of form fields only, use `Request.Form("user");`

Comment: The first two files I posted are working exactly how I want them to work. It's the file called "front.asp" that I'm having trouble with. I want the 'Click Here' link to have a variable in it based on the value inputted from the form. If no value is inputted, I want the link to be defaulted to my username,"mhammonds." @Diodeus

Comment: @Diodeus - the OP's form has the attribute `method="get"` so he is basically passing a querystring value

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP code is executed server side when the page loads. You are submitting a form inside an iframe, and the result page is also displayed inside the iframe.  This result can't change anything on the parent page because it has already been loaded.  The easiest way around this would be to have all your code on the same page.  I'll show you how to do this with VBS as the scripting language, it's what I'm used to, but it should be easy enough to use server side JS instead

```
<%@ language="VBScript"%>
<%
 Dim id
 If Request("user") <> "" then
 id = Request("user")
 else
 id = "mhammonds"
 End if
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Site</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <a href="http://www.tvcmatrix.com/<%= id %>" target="_blank" name="link">Click Here!</a><br />
        <% If Request("Submit") <> "Submit" then %>
            <form method="get">
        Your TVC Matrix Associate ID: <input type="text" name="user" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <% else 
        Response.Write("Your URL is: www.mca.com/?user=" & id)
        End If %>
    </body> 

</html>
```

If you really don't want to have to reload front.asp then you need to look at ajax, and add the relevant tag to your question

Comment: I apologize. I should have elaborated a little bit more. I want the parent page to stay the same. I want the links to change based on the query string value. When they input a value into the form I don't want the links to change immediately. The iframe outputs a url with a query string attached echoing whatever username they inputted that the user can copy and paste into the browser. Once they c&p that url the links are then changed based on the query string.  Let me know if you need an example so you can better understand the exact help I need. I really appreciate anything. @John